# Windows Media Player - always show Current Time/Total Time

Tags: display, windows-media-player, time

I'm using Windows Media Player 12 on Windows 7. When I open a video file then it by default only shows the **current position (time)**. If I click on it once then it changes to format **Current Time / Total Time**

[image: WMP time display]

Is there any way to make this format permanent (registry hack/some setting I have not noticed)? Right now every time I close WMP and open another file it's back to the default (only current time) setting.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, click on the time elapsed displayed next to progress bar, and see it switches between three states:
 - Time elapsed
 - Time remaining
 - Time elapsed / Time remaining

Comment: yeah and when you close and open WMP it resets the the default state.